# Slave leakage with levels between min and max?

Tags: clutch, rover

Rover 75 v6 Petrol. My clutch went and had to have it towed back to my house. I was told the slave has a leak. I’ve checked the reservoir and the level is between min and max. My question is, can I top up the levels or is this going to be expensive to fix?

Comment: If the fluid level is within the min-max limits, that is not the cause of the problem. I would guess the "leak" means an *internal* leak past one of the seals, which means the clutch pedal doesn't work, but you are not losing fluid out of the system. If that guess is right, the most reliable fix is a new slave cylinder, rather than trying to refurbish the old one. A quick Google search gave cylinder prices in the £50-£100 range, and it should be a simple job to change it - you don't have to take anything else apart to get access to it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: you didn't specify.  I hope you're asking about clutch

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a leak at the slave, you most likely won't be able to drive it (and wouldn't want to for safety reasons) so you shouldn't top off and go, plus the air that was sucked back into the fluid lines would make it nearly impossible to drive anyways.  These are not expensive fixes for you to do and actually quite easy (provided that you have the tools and can get a friend to help you bleed the line), and by far not an expensive fix for a shop.  Here in the states, I did my own for $60.00 for the slave and $10.00 for the fluid (I'll let you do the conversion).

If you had a sudden failure of the slave, you could have a failed master or slave cylinder that simply needs to be pumped manually (with the car off, not moving) to find where the fluid is coming out.  The sudden failure could leave the leak blocked, but not seeping until you actuate the slave.